# What is the proper way to insert a numeric value

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql

Im having issues inserting numeric. In the code the values looks OK. They have 6 decimal position. Like `-66.787735`

[image]

But when check the db looks like round the last decimal place to `-66.787730` and if I insert direct on pgAdmin insert all the decimals

[image]

In postgresql I define the field as `numeric (10,6)`

```
CREATE TABLE worker_positions
(
  worker_position_id integer NOT NULL 
                     DEFAULT nextval('worker_postiion_worker_position_id_seq'::regclass),
  worker_id integer,
  x_long numeric(10,6),
  y_lat numeric(10,6),
  event_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()
)
```

First I try with `AddWithValue` now Im trying with creating the parameter and specifying the type but same result.

```
// Insert some data
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO worker_positions (worker_id, x_long, y_lat) 
                            VALUES (@worker_id, @x_long, @y_lat)";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("worker_id", salesmanPosition.SalesmanId);

    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("x_long", salesmanPosition.x_long);
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("y_lat", salesmanPosition.y_lat);

    NpgsqlParameter p = new NpgsqlParameter("x_long", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric);
    p.Value = salesmanPosition.x_long;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
    p = new NpgsqlParameter("y_lat", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric);
    p.Value = salesmanPosition.y_lat;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Im using Postgresql 9.4 and PgAdmin III

Comment: I suspect the scale and precision are not getting inferred correctly.  Have you tried specifying them after creating the parameter? `p.Scale=6; p.Precision=10;`

Comment: @DStanley I suspect the same but don't know how specify the precision for the paramater.

Comment: I added it to my comment.

Comment: @DStanley didnt work. Still round up the 6th decimal place :(

Comment: is `salesmanPosition.x_long` a `double` or `float` or `decimal`? Floats only have 7 digits of precision but the debugger might show more.

Comment: @DStanley Yes, I thought the same. Just finish testing with `new NpgsqlParameter("x_long", NpgsqlDbType.Double);` and seem to be working better. Anyway the last decimal in gps is just meters, so at worst is 10 meters error.

Answer (score 0):

Im only interested on 6 digits so Using `NpgsqlDbType.Double` work in my case:

```
NpgsqlParameter p = new NpgsqlParameter("x_long", NpgsqlDbType.Double);
p.Value = salesmanPosition.x_long;
```